# Checking Yacc-Syntax using Regular Expression / C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex, yacc

I am working on developing a Parser , I would like to check Yacc Syntax using Regular Expression.
But It seems that it doesn't work out

```
       // Yacc-like grammar specifications

//        Ligne ::= Expr '\n' {printf("%d \n" , $1)}
//        Expr : Exp '+' Terme {$$ = $1 + $3; } | Terme ;
//        Terme : Terme '*' Facteur  {$$ = $1 * $3; } | Facteur ;  
//        Facteur : '(' Expr ')'  {$$ = $2; } | Chiffre ;  


String YaccProdS = @"($$)+ [=] [$]+[0-9][^']([$]+[0-9])*";
Check = Regex.Match(Text,YaccProdS);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just looking to get what is inside of the `{}` the following will get you that, it will also group the `$id` and the operator.

```
String YaccProdS = @"(\$+)\s+=\s+(\$+\d+)(\s*([*+\/])\s*(\$+[0-9]+))?";
```

Always remember to escape your special characters, like `$`.

Comment: It works for the first one , but it doesn't work for this {$$ = $2; }

Comment: Since the action of a Yacc rule can be arbitrary C syntax, you have to tokenize C.

Comment: I modified the answer to fit those requirements

Comment: What if the rule has this?  `{ $$ = make_node('}', $1, $2); }`.

Comment: Where did that input come from? Maybe you should edit your question to have all the cases you want to match

Comment: What about this {printf("%d \n" , $1) } , Does it working  with that !

Comment: @greedybuddha : I have listed Yacc-like grammar specifications that I wanted to use . His answer fits all the requirement expect the function

Comment: No it doesn't because that is a completely different format from all the other inputs.  Also your regex made no attempt to solve that form so I didn't either.  That form would need a completely different regex to match the right variables (well at least to look nice)